# to hide the shoutcast link contained in the file index.html

Tags: hide, shoutcast

I searched without finding results, thus I am posting my question, looking for your help.

I have a shoutcast web radio station and it can be listened utilizing a web player hosted in my website.
The stream is setup as "private", thus not listed/nor "public".

However the IP and port of the server utilized for the streaming can be easily seen doing a simple "inspect element" of the page index.html as the IP and port are written in the lines dedicated to the web player.

The issue: the shoutcast server is being attacked by hackers (causing downtime) and somebody else is utilizing the link to use stream-ripping devices and this can cause royalties issues.

The Question: I would like the IP and port of the stream server not to be visible even if inspecting/analyzing the index.html. Is there a way to hide such information?

If yes, Please be specific while giving your advises, as I am not a big expert.

Thank you for your time and kind assistance.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.  Your server must be accessible if it is to be played by anyone.  All you can do is mitigate the problems you see.

- Use a host that kicks out known attackers automatically.
- Kick long-running streamers
- Block known ripping user-agents

All three of these are extremely weak techniques in the end, but it's all you have.